# Conversion of text to picture-message?

Tags: java, text, smpp

Friends,
I need to know how to **convert a text to a picture-message(.ota) format** in JAVA for sending through mobiles? I am developing a software that sends the picture-message to another mobile via serial-port.

Could anyone help for creating a routine for the conversion process? I need that routine to converts the given text/picture to a .ota format?

Answer (score 0):

Having read the [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTA_bitmap) about the file format I would say it doesn't sound all that complicated. The basic steps are pretty much outlined and could be implemented within the hour.. Guessing you've that that already by now?

(And if so, mind sharing the code to solve the question? ;) Shouldn't need to be anything over a few hundred lines, right?)

Comment: I dont have that code... If you had, give it here. Let me try it out.